# Python -> Get children of json response

Tags: python, json

I am working with an API and the response is a json format.

But I have no Idea how to access the children data.

This is how the json looks like:

```
{'Error': None, 'Total': '1', 'AggregatedTitles': [{'MarketHashName': 'Crazy Love SAP', 'Offers': {'BestPrice': '1.5', 'Count': 3}, 'Orders': {'BestPrice': '0.8', 'Count': 5}, 'GameID': 'rust'}]}
```

How would I access the data of "BestPrice" for Offers and Orders

Hoping for an "easy" way to do it since I am pretty new to python

This is what I tried:

```
print(price["AggregatedTitles"]['Offers']['BestPrice'])
```

But this was the output:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Note that what you're showing is not JSON: strings in JSON (including property names) _must_ use double quotes. But if it were JSON, you just parse the data with json.load() or json.loads() (depending on whether you're loading from file or directly from a JSON string)  and then you just work with the resulting dict, same as you would any other Python dict. As for the error you got: as per the data you're showing, `AggregatedTitles` would be a list of dicts. So you need to access its elements like you would any other list's elements, using numerical indices.

Comment: `'AggregatedTitles': [...` The `[` tells you that the value for this key is a list.  So it should be access with list syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the structure of the data you posted, and that you got the error `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`, I assume you already converted the json into a `dict`.

What you're missing is that the value of `'AggregatedTitles': [{'MarketHashName': 'Crazy Love SAP', 'Offers': {'BestPrice': '1.5', 'Count': 3}, 'Orders': {'BestPrice': '0.8', 'Count': 5}, 'GameID': 'rust'}]` is a list with only one item, so you need to access this item with its index `0`:

```
price["AggregatedTitles"][0]["Offers"]["BestPrice"]
```

```
1.5
```